# select list with edit in React.js

Tags: reactjs

i have a select list in my form when a new user is registers the select list contains departments.

when user click on edit button the select list automatically select the department that is selected at the time of registration.Edit form has also other fields that are automatically filled in text box but select list not slecting auto that department.

Here is my code i have tried like this but this did not work only problem is that to select automatically list item.

```
<div className="form-group">
     <label>Department Name </label>
     <select className="form-control" name="empDep" id="empDep" value={this.props.emp_dep }>
          {this.state.depsDropDown.map(dep =>
               <option key={dep.DepartmentID} value={dep.DepartmentID}>{dep.DepartmentName}</option>
           )}
     </select>
</div>
```

Comment: is your `this.props.emp_dep` is id a of department or name ?

Comment: this is name of department

Comment: this.props.emp_dep and dep.DepartmentId should be same. See the example hope it can help you https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/JbbEzX?editors=0010

Comment: @AmolBJamkar i can also access the emp_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`options` tags `value` should be the same as `select` tag `value`.
In your case, you are passing department name to `select` tag value and id to `option` tag `value`.

If you change `option` tag `value` to department name then it should work, see the code,

```
<div className="form-group">
     <label>Department Name </label>
     <select className="form-control" name="empDep" id="empDep" value={this.props.emp_dep }>
          {this.state.depsDropDown.map(dep =>
               <option key={dep.DepartmentID} value={dep.DepartmentName}>{dep.DepartmentName}</option>
           )}
     </select>
</div>
```

Note: This is just workaround, best practice would be saving department id in db.

```
 getEmpId = (name) => {
    const { depsDropDown } = this.state;
    let id = "";
    for(let i = 0; i< depsDropDown.length; i++) {
      let val = depsDropDown[i]
      if(val.DepartmentName === name){
        id = val.DepartmentID
      }
    }
    return id;
  }
```

Update the select mark up as

```
<select className="form-control" name="empDep" id="empDep" value={this.getEmpId(this.props.emp_dep)}>
```

and option mark up as,

```
<option key={dep.DepartmentID} value={dep.DepartmentID}>{dep.DepartmentName}</option>
```

Comment: that is working according to your answer but their is problem i want `value` as ID it is showing `value` as Department Name. so how to fix that ?

Comment: Search in `depsDropDown` for the department record and then get the Id and pass to `select` tag `value`. Or store id in `emp_dep` while creating a record  and pass id in both `select` and `option` tag value.

Comment: can you please update the answer that would be nice?